# Why AWS S3 uses objects and not file & directories

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Why AWS S3 uses objects and not file & directories is there any specific reason to not have directories/folders in s3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are welcome to use directories/folders in Amazon S3. However, please realise that they do not actually exist.

Amazon S3 is not a filesystem. It is an object storage service that is highly scalable, stores trillions of objects and serves millions of objects per second. To meet the demands of such scale, it has been designed as a **Key-Value store**. The name of the file is the *Key* and the contents of the file is the *Object*.

When a file is uploaded to a directory (eg `cat.jpg` is stored in the `images` directory), it is actually stored with a filename of `images/cat.jpg`. This makes is *appear* to be in the `images` directory, but the reality is that **the directory does not exist** -- rather, the name of the object **includes the full path**.

This will not impact your normal usage of Amazon S3. However, **it is not possible to rename a directory** because the directory does not exist. Instead, rename the file to rename the directory. For example:

```
aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/images/cat.jpg s3://my-bucket/pictures/cat.jpg
```

This will cause the `pictures` directory to magically appear, with `cat.jpg` inside it. There is not need to create the directory first, because it doesn't actually exist. This is because the user interface is making it *appear* as though there are directories.

**Bottom line:** Feel free to use directories, but be aware that they do not actually exist and can't be renamed.